# Image height and with match parent without distortion in a browser for all device screens and orientations using React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, screen, fullscreen

In react I have a slideshow component and I want the images to best fit on any device screen and orientation. What I mean by best fit is that I want the image to grow/shrink until it hits a either the top and bottom borders or left and right borders while maintaining the same aspect ratio. I don't want any of the image hiding behind a scrollview.

Currently, the component's functionality is off but you can see what I've done so far if it helps. This solution also bugs out like crazy on mobile when you change the orientation and zoom in & out.

For simplicity, I included a similar component that just takes in one image but has the same styling ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-neco-jgogb3?file=/src/FullscreenImage.tsx))

**FullscreenImage.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import useWindowDimensions from "./hooks/useWindowDimensions";

interface IProps {
  imageUrl: string;
}

const FullscreenImage = (props: IProps) => {
  const { imageUrl } = props;
  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <div style={{ width: width, height: height }}>
      <img
        style={{
          height: width <= height ? "auto" : height,
          width: height > width ? width : "auto",
          margin: "auto",
          display: "block"
        }}
        src={imageUrl}
        alt="picsumimage"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FullscreenImage;
```

**useWindowDimensions.tsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}

const useWindowDimensions = () => {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(
    getWindowDimensions()
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
};

export default useWindowDimensions;
```

Answer (score 0):

if i undrestood your means corectly :

use `max-width` and `max-height` property :

```
<div style={{ width: width, height: height }}>
      <img
        style={{
          margin: "auto",
          display: "block",
          maxHeight: "100%",
          maxWidth: "100%"
        }}
        src={imageUrl}
        alt="picsumimage"
      />
    </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-torvalds-gbsjul?file=/src/FullscreenImage.tsx

Comment: It's close. I'm still needing the image to grow to the top and bottom or right and left border if it's smaller than the parent container. It also messes up in mobile.

Comment: do you need to object-fit ?  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: check new version : https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-torvalds-gbsjul?file=/src/FullscreenImage.tsx

Comment: yes! that is the exact functionality i'm looking for on the web. Have you tried viewing it on your mobile device? is there any way to extend the functionality to cover mobile devices?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't grow up to the proper size if the screen is bigger than the default image size

Comment: i set object-fit to cover check it : https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-torvalds-gbsjul?file=/src/FullscreenImage.tsx